# Magento 2 training courses

Tags: magento2, magento-u-courses

Can anyone help me to find online training courses for Magento 2?
I need training courses which cover from scratch to advanced, which also provides certification also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Best course to learn Magento2 from scratch - [Click Here](https://www.mage2.tv/)

But for the Certification you only need to go with Here - [Click here](https://u.magento.com/certification)

Comment: Thank u.............

Answer (score 0):

I think for certifications you need to take exams. You won't be able to get the certification by finishing any courses.